# My PC wont boot any OS after Installing Ubuntu(custom/"something else") install

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows

I'm trying to dual boot Ubuntu with my Windows10. I follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-vZ-eoH2a4U) tutorial. After the installation is completed and I restarted the computer, it says that there's no OS in the hard drive. I tried to re-install Ubuntu and it says that there's already Windows and Ubuntu installed(where before it asks: do I want to install it alongside windows, complete install, or custom install which is the one I did).

I re-installed Ubuntu, and it still says that there's no OS.

More Info:

- Windows Ver=win10home
- Ubuntu ver=latest(22.04.03)
- Device= HP EliteBook 840g2
- Bios Type=Legacy
- Current OS(where im typing this)=the "try ubuntu"

Please ask if there is any other information needed.

Comment: Again vendors using "BIOS" description for UEFI systems. Your system is UEFI and should have UEFI installs. Microsoft required vendors to install in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drives starting with release of Windows 8 in 2012. Only boot in UEFI boot mode. And after install HP only works if you manually change boot order in UEFI/BIOS settings. HP - escape + F9 for UEFI boot menu, F10 for UEFI/bios settings
Check UEFI for other settings. Make sure UEFI firmware is latest version available.

Comment: ok. i changed the bios to UEFI. But the problem is still there. Tho, now there's more options inside the "boot device" options. they are: usb external, efi filesystem, os boot manager. any idea?

Comment: I do not have HP, but have seen this: Screenshot of HP's UEFI settings change of boot order
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2490924&page=2 & 
https://www.phoronix.com/news/HP-BIOSCFG-For-Linux-6.6